# ¿Como lleno un arraylist de varios objetos usando interfaz?

Tags: java, arraylist, objeto, interfaz-gráfica, bluej

EDIT

Lo quiero es imprimir los 11 jugadores que el usuario digite en la interfaz.

Jugador es un objeto con los datos string dorsal,nombre apellido y posicion.
verjugador es donde esta toda la interfaz que ven abajo.
Controlador es listener donde le añado funcion a el boton mostrar y agregar
t1,t2,t3,t4 son los JTextfield
jugador1 es el nombre del arraylist tipo Jugador

no importa como se guarde los jugadores, solo necesito saber eso asi que no hay problema en cambiar el codigo.

[image: Interfaz de la imagen]

Adjunto el código donde estoy llenando todo.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eve) 
    { 
        try{
            if (eve.getActionCommand().contentEquals("Agregar"))
            {
                String dorsal= this.verEquipo.t1.getText();
                String nombre= this.verEquipo.t2.getText();
                String apellido= this.verEquipo.t3.getText();
                String posicion= this.verEquipo.t4.getText();

                jugador.setDorsal(dorsal);
                jugador.setNombre(nombre);
                jugador.setApellido(apellido);
                jugador.setPosicion(posicion);

                jugador1.add(jugador);

            }
            else if (eve.getActionCommand().contentEquals("Mostrar"))
            {

                imprimir();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){ e.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public void imprimir(){
        Integer size=jugador1.size();
         for(int i=0;i<jugador1.size();i++){
         System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getDorsal());
         System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getNombre());
         System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getApellido());
         System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getPosicion());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Probaste limpiando cada variable antes de insertar? -> `string dorsal = ""` y asi sucesivamente; aunque personalmente **crearia un objeto de tipo Jugador dentro de tu if** y setearia cada propiedad en desmedro de crear tantas variables para guardar los valores

Comment: Por favor por un [mcve]

Comment: Hola, no sabria como ponerlo ya que tengo 4 clases y me es imposible aislar solo esta parte de codigo, edite la pregunta y deje solo la porción de codigo que tengo hasta el momento, no importa si tengo que cambiar todo, lo que necesito que al hacer click en agregar puede meter 11 jugadores y imprimirlos que eso seria lo de menos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes crear un objeto nuevo al cual le agregarás las propiedades del jugador de esta forma se agregarán todos los elementos a el `ArrayList`:

```
if (eve.getActionCommand().contentEquals("Agregar"))
            {
                String dorsal= this.verEquipo.t1.getText();
                String nombre= this.verEquipo.t2.getText();
                String apellido= this.verEquipo.t3.getText();
                String posicion= this.verEquipo.t4.getText();

                jugador = new Jugador(); //*Crea nuevo objeto.

                jugador.setDorsal(dorsal);
                jugador.setNombre(nombre);
                jugador.setApellido(apellido);
                jugador.setPosicion(posicion);

                jugador1.add(jugador);

            }
```

y al imprimir, se mostrarán correctamente los valores de los jugadores.

```
public void imprimir(){
    // Integer size=jugador1.size();
     for(int i=0;i<jugador1.size();i++){
     System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getDorsal());
     System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getNombre());
     System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getApellido());
     System.out.println(jugador1.get(i).getPosicion());
    }
}
```